# NSURLRequest with HTTP Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, rest

I am trying to authenticate to a HTTP RESTful site using NSURLRequest from an iPhone app. I put the user/pass encoded in base64 and pass it in as the "Authorization" header in the NSURLRequest with the word "Basic " appended to it. However, I keep getting an auth error in the other end. Here is my code. If I do a manual CURL request, it works. I also checked to make sure the Base64 is properly encoded and user, pass, and url are correct.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSString *basicAuthCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", user, pass];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)];
authValue = [authValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
[urlRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
NSData *httpData = [self encodeDictionary:data];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:httpData];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest  returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: Any reason for a synchronous request and not asynchronous?

Comment: Why do you have this line - authValue = [authValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]; Everything else seems ok.

Comment: It looks like I forgot the slash in the URL. Thanks for the answers and sorry about that. The reason for synchronous is this is a shared method called by other ViewControllers (this is in the AppDelegate).

Answer (score 1):

The auth code looks fine. Sure, the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is unnecessary, but doesn't hurt. And I might use the native base64 methods (`NSData` methods `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` or `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` in iOS 7, `base64Encoding` in iOS  versions prior to 7) rather than AFNetworking's, but I don't think this is the problem either.

Assuming your userid and password are correct and that your server really is using basic authentication (which I assume is correct if your cURL is succeeding), the only thing that is obviously incorrect here is the call to `setHTTPBody` for a `GET` request. `NSURLConnection` will not send the body for a `GET` request (nor should it, as the body is semantically meaningless in `GET` requests). If you want to send a request with a body, you should generally use `POST`. Or if you want to send parameters in a `GET` request, you can add them to the URL, but not to the body.

Comment: I figured out the error (it was in the URL) but I will keep the HTTP body in mind when using POST and GET. Thanks!